# Multiple URLs to one Wordpress install

Tags: domain-mapping

i've got a wordpress install running on example.org and I want to switch it over to example.ca. I **think** I've got everything on the server and DNS set up correctly but i'm afraid I've missed something. When i change my settings to example.ca I don't want to lose  access to my admin panel. I would like to temporarily make both URLs work before committing to the switch over, is there a way to do have one install serve the same content to multiple domains?

Comment: You could modify your local hosts file to create the temporary routing.  This would allow you to test what will happen after you update the public DNS.

Comment: I need to make sure my DNS is set up correctly on dreamhost. Don't have the site running locally at all. Basically I need to test that dreamhost is doing the right thing TM before making any changes to the wordpress admin console.